# Good real analysis book to practice questions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am preparing for exams and understand the proofs of real analysis but when it comes to solving excercises or proving different types of theorems I can't do them.

Also most books I have seen on real analysis don't feature normed spaces so one with this as well as metric spaces would be useful.

Is there a good analysis book to practice questions? preferably free and with hints or answers.

Comment: What level of study are you at? Undergraduate or graduate?

Comment: Undergraduate. Thanks.

Comment: Rosenlicht's *Introduction to Analysis* is the text I used for my undergraduate analysis course. It has a fair number of exercises, and extensive treatment on metric spaces.

Comment: As for "normed spaces," do you mean Banach, Hilbert, and $L^p$ spaces? Because those aren't usually seen at the undergraduate level. I can't think of a book that would cover these without assuming some knowledge of measure theory (which again isn't usually seen at the undergraduate level).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I am not sure - it was introduced after metric spaces but not in huge detail. We only really got upto fact that any norm space can be defined as some metric and a complete normed space is Banach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [*A Problem Book in Real Analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441912959) by Aksoy and Khamsi. Each chapter contains a brief summary, about 30 questions, and detailed solutions!

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 2):

The textbook $\mathit{Real\,Analysis \,-\,A \, Long \,Form\,Mathematics \, Textbook}$ by Jay Cummings is used heavily in my department by both undergraduate and graduate students to supplement others texts used by our profs. You could probably find a pdf somewhere, but buying it on amazon is very affordable, less than $20.00 USD. I will post an amazon link below.
It should contain what you are looking for.

[https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Long-Form-Mathematics-Textbook/dp/1077254547/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=analysis&qid=1575252141&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1077254547)

Comment: Thanks! It definitely looks worth buying. Checked out the free sample and the layout is especially clean.